# Docusaurus: Multiple authors in blog post

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I'm just concidering a few SSR, and it appears [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io) seems to be a good fit. However, there is one feature I'm missing for the [Blog](https://docusaurus.io/docs/blog), which is multiple authors. As much as I can see, the examples always have one author only.

**How would it be possible to add *multiple authors*?**
(I guess by changing the template?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Currently version v2.0.0-alpha.73 dated 16 April 2021 does not allow multiple authors for a blog post.

However, a [request](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/discussions/4527) has been made in this sense, to be continued ...

Comment: Thanks, seen that! I only wondered whether a theme could be modified in a way that it displays multiple authors. Let's say by defining a list of authors in the markdown and printing each through a map function. Unfortunately, it's relatively timely. (https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/master/packages/docusaurus-theme-classic/src/theme/BlogPostItem/index.tsx)